# Two object arrays: merge with same key

Tags: javascript

I have two object arrays. I want to merge with key with value

```
var a = [{"fit":["34","32","30","28"],"size":["x"]}]

var b = [{"size":["s","m","xl"],"fit":["36"]}]
```

Expected Output should be

```
Obj=[{"fit":["34","32","30","28","36"],"size":["x,"s","m","xl"]}]
```

My Code is

```
let arr3 = [];

b.forEach((itm, i) => {
  arr3.push(Object.assign({}, itm, a[i]));
});

alert(JSON.stringify(arr3))

it gives [{"size":["x"],"fit":["34","32","30","28"]}] which wrong.
```

Comment: will `a` and `b` always have the same length ?

Comment: no they are vary ..data comes dynamically

Comment: there are attribute set fit,size,color,etc so it object array key may change dynamically

Answer (score 1):

combine `a` and `b` in a single array then reduce it starting with an array having an object with empty `fit` and `size` arrays:

```js
var a = [{ fit: ["34", "32", "30", "28"], size: ["x"] }];

var b = [{ size: ["s", "m", "xl"], fit: ["36"] }];

var obj = [...a, ...b].reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    Object.keys(curr).forEach(k => {
      acc[0][k] = [...new Set([...(acc[0][k] || []), ...curr[k]])];
    });

    return acc;
  },
  [{}]
);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: here i want to mention that fit,size names comes dynamically.. kindly treat as key

Comment: values are repeating [{"fit":["32","34","32","34"],"color":["black"]}]

Comment: in that case you might want to use `new Set` which is a list of unique values, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
// Combine into single array (spread operator makes this nice)
const myArray = [...a, ...b];

// "reduce" values in array down to a single object
const reducedArray = myArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return [{fit: [...acc.fit, ...val.fit], size: [...acc.size, ...val.size]}];
});
```

Edit: if you want the reducer to merge objects regardless of what keys and fields it has then you can do by iterating over the keys of the objects and merging them dynamically:

```
const reducedArray = myArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const returnObject = {};
  for (const eaKey in acc) {
    returnObject[eaKey] = [...acc[eaKey], ...val[eaKey]];
  }
  return [returnObject];
});
```

If the fields of the objects aren't guaranteed keys then you will need to get even more dynamic in detecting the type of merge and how to do it, but it's possible and I will leave that as an exercise for you to figure out. :)

Note that if there are duplicate values in each of the "fit" and "size" arrays, they will not be deduplicated. You'd have to do that manually as a separate step either with extra logic in the reduce function or afterwards.

Comment: there are attribute set fit,size,color,etc so it object array key may change dynamically.. so please not consider fit, size only as key

Comment: @ashutosh Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `combine` function that takes `fit` and `size` from any two objects and merges them.

Use it as a reducer to combine everything.

```
let combine = ({fit, size}, {fit: fit2, size: size2}) => 
    ({ fit: [...fit, ...fit2], size: [...size, ...size2] });

let result = [...a, ...b].reduce(combine);
```

---

### Example:

```js
var a = [{"fit":["34","32","30","28"],"size":["x"]}, {"fit": ["10", "11"], "size":["xxxxxxxxl"]}]

var b = [{"size":["s","m","xl"],"fit":["36"]}];
let combine = ({fit, size}, {fit: fit2, size: size2}) => 
({ fit: [...fit, ...fit2], size: [...size, ...size2] });

let result = [...a, ...b].reduce(combine);


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the keys directly you could try

```
const arr3 = b.reduce((carry, current, index) => {
    Object.keys(current)
    .forEach(key => {
       Object.assign(carry, { [key]: Array.prototype.concat.call(current[key], a[index][key])});
    });
    return carry;
}, {});
```